# how to implement ng-model value from another view in ionic

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I want to display ng-model value from page to input in another page

> I Want display selected issue from issues page to contact page

Issue Controller

```
.controller('IssueCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
 $http.get('api/issues').then(function(resp) {
    console.log('Success', resp);
    $scope.issues = resp.data;
  }, function(err) {
    console.error('ERR', err);
    $scope.issues = err;
  });
})
```

Contact Controller

```
.factory('Post', function($resource) {
  return $resource('api/add_new_order',{problem: "@problem"});
})
.controller('ContactCtrl', function($scope, Post) {
  // Get all posts
  $scope.posts = Post.query();
  // Our form data for creating a new post with ng-model
  $scope.postData = {};
  $scope.newPost = function() {
    var post = new Post($scope.postData);
    post.$save();
  }
$scope.issues = {};
$scope.answer = function(){
    console.log($scope.issues.name);
}
})
```

Issue View

```
<ion-list ng-repeat="item in issues">
  <ion-radio ng-model="issues.name" ng-value="'{{item.issue}}'">
    {{item.issue}}
  </ion-radio>
</ion-list>
```

Contact View

```
<form ng-submit="newPost()">
<label class="item item-input">
  <span class="input-label">Problem :</span>
  <input type="text" name="problem" ng-model="postData.problem">
</label> 
</form>
```

Comment: create sharable service. add value to service variable from one view and access it on another

Answer (score 0):

Your API requests should be on independent services, so they can be accessed by any controller.
As you seen to know how a factory works, I will give you an example.

```
.factory('IssuesService', function($http) {
  var issues = []; 
  return {
      all: function() {
          return $http.get('api/issues')
          .then(function(data){ // Optional callback inside service
              issues = data;
          });      
      }
  }
})
.controller('ContactCtrl', function($scope, Post, IssuesService) {
 ... 
  $scope.issues = [];
  IssuesService.all().then(function(data){ 
      $scope.issues = data;
  })

 ...
})
.controller('IssueCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
 IssuesService.all()
   .then(function(resp) {
    console.log('Success', resp);
    $scope.issues = resp.data;
  }, function(err) {
    console.error('ERR', err);
    $scope.issues = err;
  });
})
```